# Issue closing a video when it ends with OpenCV VideoCapture by clicking two keys

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

I'm trying to close a video when it ends by clicking two keys (n and p) using OpenCV (Python).
However, I can't understand why it doesn't work by adding the specific line to the end of the loop.
In fact, using this specific code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a VideoCapture object and read from input file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('randomvideo.mpg')

# Check if video opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening file")

# Read until video is completed
while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(25)
```

I can lock the video at the end of its playback, but by adding this:

```
# Break the loop
  else:
    if 0xFF == (ord('n')) or 0xFF == (ord('p')):
       break
```

I'm not able to close it by pressing the two keys.

Any suggestions?

P.S. Is there also a way to record which key has been pressed?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record which key is pressed by checking the return value from `cv2.waitKey()`. From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey):

> It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

So you can check if `n` or `p` is pressed like this

```
key = cv2.waitKey(25)
if key == ord('n') or key == ord('p'):
    break
```

---

Here's a working version of your code

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('randomvideo.mpg')

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error opening file")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)
    if key == ord('n') or key == ord('p'):
        break
```

Comment: One last question: when I add to this code the line print(key) in order to obtain the return value of the key pressed the result is always -1. My goal is to obtain "p" or "n" (that are pressed at the end of the video), but I'm not able to do it. Suggestions?

Comment: If there is no key pressed the value should be `-1`. When `p` is pressed I get `112` and when `n` is pressed I get 110. Maybe it's printing so fast that you miss the key code?